# Insert a word into a binary search tree C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to build a binary search tree , that store word/definition pairs.

so my struct is like this :

```
struct BinarySearchTree_t
{
    char *word,*def;
    struct BinarySearchTree_t *left;
    struct BinarySearchTree_t *right;
};
typedef struct BinarySearchTree_t BinarySearchTree;
```

So I've been blocked in insertWord function that inserts a word/definition pair in a binary search tree. Neither the word nor the definition may be NULL. NULL is considered as a special value. If the word already exists then this function replaces the current definition by the new one and returns the old one.

This is the function:

```
char* insertWord(BinarySearchTree *tree, char *word, char *definition)
{
    int r;
    char* a;

    if((tree==NULL))
    {
        BinarySearchTree* tmp;
        tmp = malloc( sizeof( BinarySearchTree ) );
        tmp->word= malloc((strlen(word)+1)*sizeof(char));
        tmp->def = malloc((strlen(definition)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(tmp->word, word);
        strcpy(tmp->def , definition);
        tmp->left = NULL;
        tmp->right = NULL;

        *tree = *tmp;
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        a= tree->word;
        r= strcmp(a,word);
        if(r = 0)
        {
            char* ret= tree->def;
            strcpy(tree->word, word);
            strcpy(tree->def , definition);
            return ret;
        }
        else if(r<0)
           return insertWord((tree->right),word,definition);
        else
           return insertWord((tree->left),word,definition);

    }
}
```

What is the problem?

---

**Edited** : the correct function:

```
char* insertWord(BinarySearchTree **tree, char *word, char *definition) 
    {                                                                   
    int r;
    char* a;

    if(((*tree)==NULL) || ((*tree)!=NULL && (*tree)->mot==NULL))
    {
        BinarySearchTree* tmp;
        tmp = malloc( sizeof( BinarySearchTree ) ); 
        tmp->left = NULL;                           
        tmp->right = NULL;                          

        tmp->mot = malloc((strlen(word)+1)*sizeof(char));
        tmp->def = malloc((strlen(definition)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(tmp->mot , word);                    
        strcpy(tmp->def , definition);              

        *tree = tmp;
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        a= (*tree)->mot;
        r= strcmp(a,word);
        if(r == 0)
        {
            char* ret= (*tree)->def;
            strcpy((*tree)->mot , word);
            strcpy((*tree)->def , definition);
            return ret;
        }
        else if(r<0)
            return insertWord(&((*tree)->right),word,definition); 
        else
            return insertWord(&((*tree)->left),word,definition);
    }
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(tree->mot , word);` where is this member `mot` in your structure?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  What is the problem you are seeing?  Does the code compile?  Does the code crash when it is run?  Does the code run but produce the wrong answer?  My money's on 'it crashes' because you have `*tree = *tmp` in `if ((tree == NULL))` (where the double parentheses are not necessary and can suppress helpful compiler warnings).

Comment: You might find it easier to use a `strdup()` function. On POSIX-ish systems, it is available anyway; if it isn't, you can use `extern char *strdup(const char *str);` to declare it and `char *strdup(const char *str) { size_t len = strlen(str) + 1; char *dup = malloc(len); if (dup != 0) memmove(dup, str, len); return dup; }`.

Comment: There are going to be other problems too; memory leaks, and so on.  You have `if (r = 0)` which is never going to execute the following code, followed by `else if (r < 0)` which is also never going to execute the following recursive call because you previous set `r` to 0 (because you mistyped `==` as `=`), so if your code survives to the `else` block, that will always be executed.  You'll eventually discover that you need to pass a `BinarySearchTree **proot` to the function so that you can set the value of the `BinarySearchTree *root = 0;` in the calling code, and pass `&root` to the insert.

Comment: @Gopi: at a guess, the OP speaks French natively, and their structure had `mot` in lieu of `word`, and the translation to English for SO missed that instance of `mot`.

Comment: Gopi i edited it , thanx 
@JonathanLeffler , sorry im new here , the problem is thet the code crash when it is run
thanx i also noticed this if(r = 0)

Comment: The revised version of the code still has problems, including memory leaking and potentially writing out of bounds of allocated memory.  For example, if you replace the definition `"cat" --> "feline"` with `"cat" --> "purring critter"`, the new definition writes outside the bounds of the memory allocated for the old definition.  However, it is considerably better than it was.  (Officially, you should error check every memory allocation, too.  It might be easiest to replace direct calls to `malloc()` with a call to `xmalloc()` which implements the check and exits if the allocation fails.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you mean those lines ?
     char* ret= (*tree)->def;
     strcpy((*tree)->mot , word);
     strcpy((*tree)->def , definition);

for example if the word already exists , the new definition would take the place of the old with this strcpy((*tree)->def , definition); , did i need to free memory in (*tree)->def first ?
or what's the idea ?

Comment: You need to think carefully about the memory management, yes.  And the `strcpy()` operations worry me, because you don't know how much space there was to use, but you blindly copy the new definition over the old one.  That's OK if the new is no longer than the old, but a longer new definition leads to writing out of bounds — bad news.  Also, you copy the new word over the old word, even though you know they're the same, so the copy isn't really necessary.  In my code (in my answer), I freed the old definition and `strdup()`'d to make a copy of the new one.

Comment: alright , i understood now ; thanx a lot ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are trying to initialize the pointer to root of your SearchTree, the first time it's accessed, right? The problem is that you are modifying a local copy of the pointer `*tree` and not the actual pointer that's present in the parent (calling) function. If you plan to modify the pointer to your SearchTree inside the called function, you should pass a pointer to the `*tree` in call to `insertWord` (i.e. a pointer to pointer).
You should change the definition to:

> char* insertWord(BinarySearchTree **tree, char *word, char *definition)

Accordingly you should modify all accesses of `tree` inside your `insertWord` function.

Comment: That is one of the problems.  It is not the only problem, but it is one major problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, very true.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative working code — given a clean bill of health by [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct BinarySearchTree_t
{
    char *word, *def;
    struct BinarySearchTree_t *left;
    struct BinarySearchTree_t *right;
};
typedef struct BinarySearchTree_t BinarySearchTree;

static void freeTree(BinarySearchTree *root);
static void dump_tree(BinarySearchTree *root);
extern char *insertWord(BinarySearchTree **ptree, char *word, char *definition);

char *insertWord(BinarySearchTree **ptree, char *word, char *definition)
{
    if (*ptree == NULL)
    {
        BinarySearchTree *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
        tmp->word = strdup(word);
        tmp->def = strdup(definition);
        tmp->left = NULL;
        tmp->right = NULL;
        *ptree = tmp;
        return tmp->def;
    }
    else
    {
        BinarySearchTree *tree = *ptree;
        int r = strcmp(tree->word, word);
        if (r == 0)
        {
            free(tree->def);
            tree->def = strdup(definition);
            return tree->def;
        }
        else if (r < 0)
            return insertWord(&tree->right, word, definition);
        else
            return insertWord(&tree->left, word, definition);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *word_defs[][2] =
    {
        { "cat", "feline" },
        { "dog", "canine" },
        { "box", "carton" },
        { "cat", "purring critter" },
    };
    BinarySearchTree *root = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(word_defs) / sizeof(word_defs[0]); i++)
    {
        printf("%zu: Add %s => %s\n", i, word_defs[i][0], word_defs[i][1]);
        char *def = insertWord(&root, word_defs[i][0], word_defs[i][1]);
        dump_tree(root);
        printf("New definition: %s\n", def);
    }

    freeTree(root);

    return 0;
}

static void freeTree(BinarySearchTree *root)
{
    if (root != 0)
    {
        freeTree(root->left);
        freeTree(root->right);
        free(root->word);
        free(root->def);
        free(root);
    }
}

static void dump_tree(BinarySearchTree *root)
{
    if (root->left != 0)
        dump_tree(root->left);
    printf("%p: %s => %s\n", (void *)root, root->word, root->def);
    if (root->right != 0)
        dump_tree(root->right);
}
```

This version reports the new definition of the word.  The original code may have been reporting the old definition; it is not hard to fix this code so that it reports the old definition (but it requires a modicum of care to ensure that the old definition is actually released, and null pointers aren't printed).